# How list paths with length over 248?

Tags: powershell

I need create this list to allow an other program to properly work. I use this code:

```
function analyse {

    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$newPath
    )

    cd $newPath

    dir | Foreach-Object {
        $data = Get-Content -Path o:\******\public\ParcoursArborescence\Limitless\data.txt
        if ($_.PsisContainer -eq $True) {
            $testPath = $_.FullName + ";"
            $name = $testPath
            $testPath = $data -match [regex]::escape($testPath)
            $testpath

            if($testPath.Length -eq 0) {
                $name | Out-File -Append "o:\******\public\ParcoursArborescence\Limitless\data.txt"
                if ($_.FullName.Length -gt 248) {
                    "ecriture"
                    $result += $_.FullName + "`r"
                } else {
                    "nouvelle analyse"
                    $_.Fullname
                    analyse $_.FullName
                }
            }
        } else {
            $testPath = $_.Directory.FullName + ";"
            $name = $testPath
            $testPath = $data -match [regex]::escape($testPath)

            if($testPath.Length -eq 0) {
                $name | Out-File -Append "o:\******\public\ParcoursArborescence\Limitless\data.txt"
                $_.FullName.Length
                if ($_.FullName.Length -gt 260) {
                    "ecriture2"
                    $result += $_.Directory.Name + "`r"
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    $result | Out-File -Append "o:\******\public\ParcoursArborescence\Limitless\bilanLimitless.txt" 
}
```

But it takes hours and hours... I need to use this in thousands of folders. So, do you have any idea about how could it get faster ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your script a little bit ? I don't understand why you do a second analysis (`"nouvelle analyse"`). You create a recursion there.

Comment: I have to go in every folder ; I have to know if every file's path is either composed of more or less of 260 characters, because of Windows' limit. Is there something wrong in the way I created the recursion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying things here, but why not list all the files at once, and test their `FullName` `Length` (PS 3.0 needed for the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`) ?

```
$maxLength = 248

Get-ChildItem $newPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique |
    Out-File "overlength_paths.txt"
```

For PS 2.0:

```
$maxLength = 248

Get-ChildItem $newPath -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) -and (-not $_.PSisContainer) } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique |
    Out-File "overlength_paths.txt"
```

Comment: I'm using PS2, I guess -File only treats files and not directories ?

Comment: Yes. I have Added a PS2 version :-). `PSisContainer` is `$true` for directories.

Comment: Thank you ! But i still have a problem ; I'd like to write only the parent folder of the file, because I will move the entire folder when a file has an overlength path. How can I put a condition to see if the text file already contains the full adress of the folder ?

Comment: OK I understand your logic now :), I'll try to improve my snippet accordingly.

Comment: I found a very quick solution : we select the `DirectoryName` property, with the `-Unique` parameter, it gives each path only once ^^. It will be a bit longer now, I guess, maybe you can try and time it on a sample folder with `Measure-Command`.

Comment: Well I cannot do it right now, but I will try this tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97532/discussion-between-sodawillow-and-kikopu).

Comment: I wasnt on my computer anymore, that's why I couldnt keep going, sorry ! So I tried the DirectoryName, couldnt make it work. I'll ask an other question, we're going too far from the first question !